# How is jQuery added to Joomla Template Protostar

Tags: templates, jquery

I want to know how the jquery resources loaded into the Joomla Protostar Template under Joomla 3.3. If I look into the code I see the jquery resources are loaded but in the index.php I cant find any code line. Can anyone tell how the jquery resources are loaded?

Comment: Why a negative vote?

Comment: You now have the privilege to vote in our current moderator [election](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1).  Please exercise your new democratic privilege.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery automatically gets imported in **noConflict** mode when you use the following code:

```
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');
```

which also as you can probably figure out, loads the Bootstrap framework too.

You will see on line **38** of the **index.php** file in the Prosostar template folder

Comment: You can also change this to `JHtml::_('jquery.framework');` if you do not want the bootstrap framework and just jquery. I think that is only in Joomla 3+ though but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Jordan, yes, you're correct. Only Joomla 3.x, but the Protostar template is part of Joomla 3.x so all is good :)

Comment: Guess I will add, if you need to use jQuery use that code even if its being loaded somewhere else, it will only load once but if you add other scripts they will typically load above the framework unless it is above your scripts as well (mainly while using `$doc->addScript($path)`)

Comment: That's a whole new topic ;)

Answer (score 2):

In the  section of my Protostar template I can see the following - can you not?

```
<script src="/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

There is also some documentation here that may help regarding Javascript frameworks and Joomla http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Javascript_Frameworks

See on line three;

> To enable the Bootstrap framework, call
>   JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework'). This will automatically enable the
>   jQuery framework in noConflict mode (i.e. accessed via jQuery. instead
>   of $.)

Hope this is clear and helps.

Comment: Yes, if you see in the html code then I can see this, but in the index.php the files are loaded from a different way

Comment: Ok, the answer was on the 3rd line of the documentation link I provided.

Comment: I don’t understand the down vote because the answer is in the link you provide. I make a +1 and i suggest you add a quote from your link to your answer (« This will automatically enable the jQuery framework... »)

Comment: I also don't understand the down vote? Seems like a helpful answer - thanks Sébastien